# Haskell List Comprehension Non-exhaustive pattern when calling more than one parameter

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, non-exhaustive-patterns

To start with I have created a Type StudentMark which is a tuple taking firstly a String and secondly an Int.

```
type StudentMark = (String, Int)
```

This is my capMarks function:

```
capMarks :: [StudentMark] -> [StudentMark]
capMarks [cMarks] = [(st, mk) | (st, mk) <- [capMark cMarks]]
```

And here is my capMark function:

```
capMark :: StudentMark -> StudentMark
capMark (st, mk)
    |   mk > 39   =   (st, 40)
    |   mk < 40   =   (st, mk)
```

It is supposed to return:

```
[("Jo", 37), ("Sam", 40)]
```

from:

```
capMarks [("Jo", 37), ("Sam", 76)]
```

But will only return the correct and expected response when I input just 1 parameter into the function, for example:

```
capMarks [("Jake", 50)]
```

Or

```
capMarks [("Jake"), 30]
```

But using two (or more) as it's supposed to will just tell me there is a Non-exhaustive pattern in the capMarks function.

Comment: If any of my terminology is off please bear with me as I'm new to both Haskell and stackoverflow

Comment: Let's back up a step. What are you trying to accomplish with these functions? What is the purpose of this code? What problem are you actually trying to solve with this code?

Comment: It is supposed to return the tuples wherein the Integers over 40 will be returned as 40 as per the capMark function. i.e. `capMark ("Steve", 100)` would return `("Steve", 40)` so what the capMarks function is supposed to do is use the capMark function to do this for a list of tuples using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyze your `capMarks` function:

```
capMarks :: [StudentMark] -> [StudentMark]
capMarks [cMarks] = [(st, mk) | (st, mk) <- [capMark cMarks]]
```

First of all `capMarks [cMarks] = ...` is a pattern matching. This matches a list that contains a single element. I assume that you want to do something with an entire list, so change this to `capMarks cMarks = ...`

Next `... [(st, mk) | (st, mk) <- [capMark cMarks]]` will apply the `capMark` function to the only element in your original pattern matching scheme and then put the result as the only element of a list. It appears that you want to apply `capMark` to each element of a list. So if we follow the previous suggestion, you need to do something like `... [capMark mark | mark <- cMarks]`. This does exactly as stated earlier: apply `capMark` to each element of the `cMarks` list.

Final version:

```
capMarks :: [StudentMark] -> [StudentMark]
capMarks cMarks = [capMark mark | mark <- cMarks]
```

Alternatively, you can also use pattern matching and explicit recursion:

```
capMarks [] = []  
capMarks (x:xs) = capMark x : capMarks xs
```

The first line says that `capMarks` applied to an empty list is an empty list. The second line says that `capMarks` applies to a list with at least one element will apply `capMark` to the first element and then recursively apply `capMarks` to the rest of the list.

This is such a common pattern in Haskell that there is a function called `map` that generalizes it. Using `map` is incredibly simple:

```
capMarks cMarks = map capMark cMarks
```

`map` has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` which means it takes a function and a list and returns a list. (The `a` and `b` just tell the compiler which types have to be the same.) `map` then applies the function to each element in the input list.

Eventually you will learn about partial function application and point-free style. With these two concepts, the version using `map` can be simplified slightly:

```
capMarks = map capMark
```

Don't worry too much about this yet. I'm just adding it here for completeness.

Comment: Code-Apprentice, I see the issue I had now! I thought that my capMark function would have to be on the pattern matching side of the comprehension. This makes a lot more sense now, thank you.

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer I edited my question with a bit more explanation, including some alternative implementations. I hope this helps. Good luck with learning Haskell.

Comment: Ah I see how map works from your example. We've not yet been taught that but I shall bear it in mind for the future as it looks like it will get a lot of use. Your completeness is much appreciated. I have seen `(x:xs)` but not understood what it meant or how it worked.

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer I'm sure you will get to this in your class eventually. `(x:xs)` as a function parameter is a pattern which matches a list with at least one element. `x` is the first element of the list and `xs` is the rest of the list, possibly even an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You should check how pattern matching works in Haskell.

`capMarks [x]` will only match a list with one element. What you probably want is something like `capMarks myList = [ ... | ... <- f myList]` or define the rests of the cases in a recursive manner.

For example

```
capMarks [] = []
capMarks x:xs = capMark x : capMarks xs
```

This simplified "version" works in hugs

```
capMarks :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
capMarks xs = [(*) 2 x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: My Haskell is rusty :-/

Comment: I have my head around most of it, but now that it's calling on a previous function there's a lot of issues regarding mis-matching types. I follow your simplified version though.

Comment: The issue seems to me to be that the variable cMarks is a list of tuples (StudentMark) but the function capMark will only take a single StudentMark, not a list of them.

Comment: Well in haskell you have the types to think of the stuff. `capMark` can only by applied to a student, so if you are going to use comprehension to extract the elements of the list, you should apply `capMark` to the elements from the list. Think of the simplified version I just showed you, if you think `(*) 2` as a `capMark`... how would you write capMarks.

Comment: Ale, thanks for your explanation on list comprehensions. Much appreciated.

Comment: Note that pattern matching a list requires parentheses (i.e. `(x:xs)` instead of just `x:xs`).